# Basemap misalignment between Digitalglobe Maps API to Maxar EarthWatch basemap products

Tags: coordinate-system, basemap

The resulting of features created for Project2018 using DigitalGlobe Maps API (now decomissioned) and Project2019 using Maxar EarthWatch basemap (replacement product) are not aligned.

Is anyone aware of coordinate system parameters of these products and if there is a difference?

There is a 5-10m difference between features as a result of using the 2 basemaps products.

Answer (score 0):

This misalignment comes from differences in Earthwatch source imagery accuracy and orthorectification process. As a result there is approximately a +/- ~15 m difference in locations between the 2 bases for the 2018 and 2019 EarthWatch basemap imagery.

Worth noting if you are using this base to create geographic features you want to compare over the years - they may differ on the ground between ~0-15 meters.